# WL push notification callback not being invoked in iOS when app is in background

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We have push notifications working successfully. Backend event source is a Worklight adapter written in JS using the 'WL.Server.createDefaultNotification' and 'WL.Server.notifyAllDevices' API calls to send unicast notifications. In the front-end, the app is registered for push notification call back using 'WL.Client.Push.registerEventSourceCallback' JS API.

These particular scenarios are not working:

- App is open in the background after login. Notification message is received, but user does not tap notification banner message - and instead just opens app by touching app icon. Notification callback method is not called - and subsequently payload from the backend is not available for the method.
- App is open in the background after login. Notification message is received which only has iOS badge change and payload but no notification message for the banner or lock screen. In which case user has nothing to tap on. When user opens the app again - notification callback is not called.

Knowledgecenter documentation seems to indicate that the callback method should be getting invoked even if the app is running in the background. This is with Worklight 6.2.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Push is indeed supposed to work as you've describe. This is a bug.
This is no manual workaround for this.

If you are an IBM customer or Business Partner you will need to open a PMR (support ticket).